# didSelectItemAt not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have my collection view ready to go and I'm trying to do `didSelectItemAt` to segue to the detail view. But I just want to test out logging each of the items and it's not logging.

I set all the delegates already:

*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate {*

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collection.dataSource = self
        collection.delegate = self
        searchBar.delegate = self

        activityIndicatorView.isHidden = true


        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

*

What am I doing wrong?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movie : Movie

    movie = MOVIE_ARRAY[indexPath.row]
    print(movie.plot)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you set the collection view's delegate?

Comment: Check if you are not using  didDeselectItemAt indexPath instead of didSelectItemAt

Comment: didSelectItemAt was used :) googled for an hour and that's the most common mistake. Yes, the view's delegates are all set.

Comment: Here's my github - https://github.com/bwong199/IOS-Movie-Search-Application

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You have added a `TapGestureRecognizer` on the view. TapGestureRecognizer has a property `cancelsTouchesInView`.

> - var cancelsTouchesInView: Bool { get set }
>
> A Boolean value affecting whether touches are delivered to a view when a gesture is recognized.

This is `true` by default and will prevent calling didSelectItemAt since touches will not be delivered to the view after a tap is recognized.
You need to set it to `false` like this:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: you made my day

Comment: Those unexpected gesture recognizers!

Comment: I had added the tap gesture in a function in another file and was calling it like hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() on my view controller.... editing that function as per your suggestion works perfectly...

Comment: I want to disable TapGestureRecognizer work when clicking on an item (when didSelectItemAt fires).. I tried your solution but it only allowed the didSelectItemAt to execute but after this it executes it's method

Comment: Looked at this answer and went "Nah, not applicable"... and of course, guess what... APPLICABLE!!!