# collectionView didSelectItemAt indexPath not called swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I have a custom view which hold a collection view set like below.

```
func setupCollectionView() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: scaled(height: 15), left: scaled(width: 35), bottom: scaled(height: 15), right: scaled(width: 35))
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: scaled(width: 30), height: scaled(width: 30))
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 15
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 30
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.register(THTexasHoldemEmojiCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: THTexasHoldemEmojiCell.className)
}
```

and delegate functions

```
extension THTexasHoldemEmojisView {

    func setupDelegates() {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

}

extension THTexasHoldemEmojisView: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("did highlight item")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("did select item")

    }

}
```

The weird thing is the didHighlightItem function could get called, but didSelectItem will not. Did I missed something here? Thanks for any help.

My views connection is UIViewController(THController) holds the UIView(THEmojisView), THEmojisView holds the collection view.
In the THController i've got a lot of views and actions, but not cover the THEmojisView.
Is it possible that touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) of THController would affect the delegate funcs of the collection view ?

Comment: Please post code instead of screenshots from next time!

Comment: Did you set datasource and delegate?

Comment: `yourCollectionView?.delegate = self ` And
`yourCollectionView?.dataSource = self `

Comment: sorry, i just don't paste that part.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780373/didselectitemat-not-being-called this solved it for me. Had the same issue with `didHilightItem` working and `didSelectItem` not.

Answer (score 5):

i used a custom layout for my collection view and suddenly the didselect item stopped firing the event.

try add `GestureRecognizer` to your `UICollectionView`

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

self.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView)) {
//Do your stuff here

}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you have a `subview` in your Cell, whose `isUserInteractionEnabled` is `true`.

Try change the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of the subviews of Cell to `false`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Should you have a Gesturerecognizer for a parent view or viewcontroller's view - set it's `cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar problem.I have my custom UIView and add collectionView on it.I also set the datasource and delegate but I can't scroll the collectionView and the didSelectItemAt function didn't called. The point is that I set the wrong frame of collectionView

Comment: This could be comment

Answer (score 1):

just call

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
```

in your viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with *THTexasHoldemEmojiCell*. Maybe there is a *UIControl* instance inside collection view cell that handles all your touches. Simple solution is setting *isUserInteractionEnabled* property of this *UIControl* to false.

Comment: Sorry for reply so late, no there is not. There is nothing inside the cell. I've got another collectionView in this controller recently, same problem. I think there is some touch funcs covered the didSelectItem event, but I cannot find it.

Comment: THX for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you should make sure you didn't using `tapGestureRecognizer` on your `view` in the background of `collectionView`.